# Time complexity BFS

Tags: algorithm, time, graph, time-complexity, breadth-first-search

Everyone writes that in time complexity BFS there will be: O(|V|+|E|). Why it uses modals? I realized that it has something to do with the representation of the graph, but how? explain

Help me with time complexity

Comment: modals? |V| and |E| are the size of the set of vertices and the size of the set of edges respectively.

Comment: But, V and E - they are already sizes, aren't they?

Comment: Usually capital letters denote sets rather than sizes, but you'd have to consult the text you're reading which should hopefully define its terms. Or perhaps it just needs common sense... if you're writing |V| and |E| it can be assumed that V and E are sets and not sizes, since it doesn't make sense notationally if not.

Comment: Here's a typical definition of a graph that uses V and E: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory

Comment: Thanks!I finally got it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "modals" but V and E are typical names for the two sets that define a graph: V is the set of vertices, or nodes; E is the set of edges, pairs of vertices. The absolute value notation here denotes that we want the size of the two sets, the "cardinality" of the sets, their number of elements. So O(|v| + |E|) means linear over the sum of the number of vertices and the number of edges.